# how to remove hours from pandas style date index display?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

regular date index show fine, but once I add style it adds ugly midnight hours, how do I ged rid of these?
here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
now = pd.to_datetime('today').date()
df.index = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2020-05-01'), pd.Timestamp('2020-05-03'))
df
```

shows:

[image]

but adding style adds uncalled for hours:

```
S = pd.Series([True, True, False])
S.index = df.index
df_style = df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if x.name in S[S].index else '' for i in x],  axis=1)
df_style
```

[image]

I've tried:

```
df_style.index=[str(x).split()[0] for x in df_style.index]
```

but it does not help, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible you can convert values to dates:

```
df.index = df.index.date
#alternative
#df = df.set_index(df.index.date)
```

Or to strings:

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#alternative
#df = df.set_index(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```